# Jquery - How to check if classname exists

Tags: jquery, css

i want to check the style Tag if a classname exist or not.

```
if ($("head > style:eq(2)").hasClass('className')) 
{
  alert('yes');
}
```

Comment: looks like your code will work although I don't think `<style>` tags should have class names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could access the `document.styleSheets` object:

see the all way in this answer

[get CSS rule's percentage value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery)

```
<script>
    var rules = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var i=0; rules.length; i++) {
        var rule = rules[i];
        if (rule.selectorText.toLowerCase() == ".classname") {
            alert('found!!');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version, same thing, only difference is that sometimes for me selectorText is not defined

```
var rules = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
for (var i in rules) 
{
    if (typeof rules[i]['selectorText'] != 'undefined' && rules[i]['selectorText'].indexOf("fbconnect_button") >= 0) 
    {
        alert('found!!');
    }
}
```