# Getting the width of an html element in percent % with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I `alert` the element which has a css selector set to `width:100%` I get it's with in `px`, is there some way to get it in `%` as set from css, I need it to fix some script with fluid layouts.

```
// css
.my-element {
    width:100%;
}

// javascript
alert('width: '+$('.my-element').css('width'));
// this alerts "width: 1116px" instead of "width: 100%"
```

Maybe something like this is always true?

```
alert($('.my-element').outerWidth() == $('.my-element').parent().outerWidth());
```

Comment: There is a plugin which I forgot it's name that read css properties from the `css` file... :(

Comment: interesting! I never thought to need the with in `%` I think this should a useful feature for fluid layouts.

Answer (score 6):

```
function percentwidth(elem){
    var pa= elem.offsetParent || elem;
    return ((elem.offsetWidth/pa.offsetWidth)*100).toFixed(2)+'%';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the width in percentage by two methods.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dMLrR/2/)

With jQuery use jQuery 1.3.2 and you will get 100%.

```
alert($('.my-element').css('width'))​;
```

With javascript by setting width in style attribute of the tag like this

```
<div id="div2" style="width:100%"></div>

div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

alert("Width of div2 with style = " + div2.style.width);
```

Comment: This has changed prior to jQuery 1.6.4! The second alert works, though.

Answer (score -1):

This post

[Is it possible to use jQuery to get the width of an element in percent or pixels, based on what the developer specified with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006588/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-get-the-width-of-an-element-in-percent-or-pixels)

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: This only works if the element doesn't have a parent element with a width itself, wich is what the question is all about I think.

Comment: this is not always true, for example if I have `.my-element` wrapped inside another with a different width from the document.

Comment: if your parent div is 300px and your inner element is 100% both are 300px isn't it?