# How to get css property value in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the width of an element in percentage. I am using the following function to get the style but it gives the value in pixels. Here the variable style can be any css property like width, height etc.

```
this.getStyle = function(style) {
    var elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(that.element);
    var value = elementName.getPropertyValue(style);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: How do you set the width?

Comment: What about doing a manual calculation of the % using the pixel width value of the parent element?

Comment: i have set the width in percentage as 'width: 100%'

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/get-element-css-property-width-height-value-as-it-was-set-in-percent-em-px-et

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems that you're looking for

```
that.element.style.width
that.element.style.height
etc
```

Comment: It's working only if the `css` is inline style like: `<div style="width:60%">test</div>`

Comment: @MoshFeu it works even if CSS is not defined inline with latest Firefox and Chromium (tested with Firefox 56 and Chromium 62). But I think it depends of the CSS property, for example when using a CSS stylesheet, I can access width and height via element.style but not for the border property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675885/get-set-css-property-values-via-javascript-questions

Answer (score 3):

I think you get always pixels, rather than % width. The reason is while object render it always set physical width based on% we given, this you can verify  via dom. Javascript use `DOM(Document Object Model)`, while jQuery you can use Dom as well as  before load property via `document.getready()`.

So as above you can get the property, but in pixels.

```
document.getElementById('yourdivname').element.style.width
```

or

```
div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
alert("Width of div2 with style = " + div2.style.width);
```

[Getting the width of an html element in percent % with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624368/getting-the-width-of-an-html-element-in-percent-with-jquery)

This is interesting :

1. [Is it possible to use jQuery to get the width of an element in percent or pixels, based on what the developer specified with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006588/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-get-the-width-of-an-element-in-percent-or-pixels)
2. http://www.lucemorker.com/blog/javascript-vs-jquery-quick-overview-and-comparison

> $(document).ready is a jQuery event to be triggered after the HTML
>   document has been loaded vs onload is a built-in DOM event to be
>   triggered after all content has been loaded. So the ready event would
>   normally fire earlier than the onload event, allowing code execution
>   as early as possible without having to wait for all assets to be fully
>   loaded

For more details :- click this [link](https://www.quora.com/jQuery/What-is-the-difference-between-document-ready-and-body-onload-functions).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var width = (100 * parseFloat($('.largeField').css('width')) / parseFloat($('.largeField').parent().css('width')) ) + '%';
```

Comment: how do you write this in pure javascript?

Comment: The Original Poster asked for pure JavaScript, but this is jQuery Code without explanation.