# get css width of an element and convert it to percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this code:

HTML

```
<div class="bar-value"></div>
```

CSS

```
.bar-value{
    width: 50%;
    height: 28px;
    background: #8BBDE8;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var percent = $('.bar-value').css('width');
});
```

the problem is that this returns the width of the div in pixels (in this case: 200px). I want that to return the value of the div in percentage (50%).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

To get a percentage, you need the width of it's parent. Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var element = $('.bar-value');
    var percent = element.css('width')/element.parent().width()*100+'%';
});
```

Comment: i tried that code with a variaton and worked fine, thanks! will be marked as accepted answer as soon as possible

Comment: Sorry I forgot to multiply that by 100. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006588/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-get-the-width-of-an-element-in-percent-or-pixels)

You have to implement it yourself :

```
var width = $('.bar-value').css('width');
var parentWidth = $('.bar-value').offsetParent().css('width');
var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
```