# After click if CSS value equals

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

Don't know why it's not work.

when toggleClass is done,if CSS value equals do hide();

```js
$(".rwd-sec").click(function() {
      $(".rwd-main").toggleClass("is-active");
      if ($(".rwd-main").css("right") == "-84%") {
        $(".rwd-main").hide();
      }
})
```

```css
.rwd-main {
  right: -84%;
}

.rwd-main.is-active {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rwd-main">
  <div class="rwd-sec"></div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Ming_Yi/pen/VweMNOG?fbclid=IwAR1gtVfSJ_6C14H6W6mefBUeUAtOLgG)

Comment: `$(".rwd-main").css("right")` return the value in px not in percentage

Comment: @TamilSelvanC Is there a way  return the value in percentage?  that is very difficult for position menu, if return the value in px.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462600/get-css-width-of-an-element-and-convert-it-to-percentage

Comment: try `var element = $(this);
    $(".rwd-sec").css("left", "-12px");
    $(".rwd-main").toggleClass("is-active");
var percent = parseFloat( element.css('width') )/parseFloat(element.parent().width())*100+'%';
    alert(parseFloat(element.css('width')))
           if ($(".rwd-main").css("right") == percent) {
      $(".rwd-main").hide();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for this, a more simple way would be to just check if the element has the class so you dont need to check for a specific css value (which might change later on):

```
$(".rwd-sec").click(function () {
  $(".rwd-main").toggleClass("is-active");
  if ($(".rwd-main").hasClass('is-active')) {
    $(".rwd-main").hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: but I want if-statement after toggleClass finished , so I set  CSS value equals.

Hide rwd-main atfter removeclass.

Comment: the if statement is after the toggle?!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
//to find the value of the css in percentage
var percent = parseFloat( element.css('width'))/parseFloat(element.parent().width())*100+'%';
```

Ref: [get css width of an element and convert it to percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462600/get-css-width-of-an-element-and-convert-it-to-percentage)

Note: parseFloat is used convert to float of return value (eg "47px")

```js
$(".rwd-sec").click(function() {
     var element = $(this);

    $(".rwd-main").toggleClass("is-active");
    var percent = parseFloat( element.css('width'))/parseFloat(element.parent().width())*100+'%';
//alert(parseFloat(element.css('width')))
if ($(".rwd-main").css("right") == percent) {
  $(".rwd-main").hide();
}
})
```

```css
.rwd-main {
  right: -84%;
}

.rwd-main.is-active {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rwd-main">
  <div class="rwd-sec"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the other ways, in addition to @Alex's `.hasClass()`, is to use `.is()`:

```js
$(".rwd-sec").click(function() {
      $(".rwd-main").toggleClass("is-active");
      //console.log( $('.rwd-main').css('right') );
      if ($(".rwd-main").is(".is-active")) {
        $(".rwd-main").hide();
      }
})
```

```css
.rwd-main {
  right: -84%;
}

.rwd-main.is-active {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rwd-main">
  <div class="rwd-sec">X</div>
</div>
```

**Reference**

- [.is() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/is/)