# HTML - retrieve the max possible width of an inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to retrieve, in javascript, the max possible width of an HTML element with display: inline-block.
My goal is to insert some elements in a page generated by a CMS.
I need the max possible width to adjust the content to be inserted in it.

Example:

HTML:

```
<...>
<div class="ib">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="b" id="my_content">
            ...
        <div>
    <div>
</div>
<...>
```

CSS:

```
.ib {
    display: inline-block;
}
.b {
    display: block;
}
```

I can only manage the element "my_content" and it's content. The parent elements are generated by the CMS, and I cannot change anything.
Using jQuery is ok.

[EDIT]
Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kris_B/psodhaxz/) for a better explaination.
Before inserting content in #my_content, I need to know the available width.
If there's no content in #my_content, I get a width of 0, even if I set `width:100%` and `max-width:100%`.

The CMS currently generates this structure. As I don't have any control on this, it may change in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use jQuery to get the width of an element in percent or pixels, based on what the developer specified with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006588/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-get-the-width-of-an-element-in-percent-or-pixels)

Comment: To clarify, does your CMS-generated page have multiple `div.ib` elements and you want a way through JS to determine the width of the widest one?