# How can I change bg-color in jquery according to width conditional case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created progress bar and I want to change the background color of progress bar. When I change the width percentage of progress bar it doesn't change the background color according to the condition. How to fix it?

My html code is here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.myclass').css('width') <= '30 %') {
    $('.myclass').css('background-color', '#96042a');
  } else if ($('.myclass').css('width') <= '50 %') {
    $('.myclass').css('background-color', '#dfe843');
  } else if ($('.myclass').css('width') <= '80 %') {
    $('.myclass').css('background-color', '#058482');
  } else {
    $('.myclass').css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
  }
});
```

```css
.html {
  width: 43%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.width {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="html">
  <h5>html / html5</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 90%;">90%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>css / css3</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 65%;">65%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>javascript</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 45%;">45%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>jquery</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 15%;">15%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still it doesn't work

Comment: Refer to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006588/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-get-the-width-of-an-element-in-percent-or-pixels 
The problem is that the method `.css()` will not return relative percentage values, only absolute length values (like `px`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider checking against the text node values of the elements in question rather than the css values.

The `.css()` method does not return relative percentage values, only absolute unit-less pixel values, e.g: `600`, `386`, `85`, etc.

Since, in this case, the text contained within the element represents the width of the progress bar, this value can be used instead, as demonstrated in the embedded code snippet below.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

*Note:*

1. *the initial `.ready()` method has been replaced with an `.each()` method to loop through each instance.*
2. *the text value of the element in question will be logged to console through each iteration for the sake of demonstration*
3. *If you require the check to be done against inline CSS values, refer to the answer by @MattBall [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006588/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-get-the-width-of-an-element-in-percent-or-pixels#answer-4006610)*

```js
$('.myclass').each(function() {
  var innerVal = $(this).text();
  console.log(innerVal);
  if(innerVal.length > 2) {
    if (innerVal <= '3') {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#96042a');
    } else if (innerVal <= '5') {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#dfe843');
    } else if (innerVal <= '8') {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#058482');
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
    }
  } else if (innerVal.length < 3) { 
    if (innerVal.split('')[1] == '%') {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#96042a');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.html {
  width: 43%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.width {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="html">
  <h5>html / html5</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 90%;">90%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>css / css3</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 65%;">65%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>javascript</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 45%;">45%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>jquery</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 15%;">15%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>php</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 10%;">10%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>msql</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 5%;">5%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>coffee machine</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 79%;">79%</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="html">
  <h5>cleaning the coffee machine</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="myclass" style="width: 0%;">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but in this case if you write 5% then it'll know as 50% 4%for 40 6 for 60 how can i handle this?

Comment: To account for that, an additional conditional check has been added to check the length of the string values. (answer updated)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help now it's working hundred percent

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Remove the space between your percentages in jquery like this and it should work. I added a for loop to iterate each one individually try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myClass = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
    for (i = 0; i < myClass.length; i++) {
      if (myClass[i].css('width') <= '30%') {
        myClass[i].css('background-color', '#96042a');
      } else if (myClass[i].css('width') <= '50%') {
        myClass[i].css('background-color', '#dfe843');
      } else if (myClass[i].css('width') <= '80%') {
        myClass[i].css('background-color', '#058482');
      } else {
        myClass[i].css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: it does work but because you used a bunch of if statements selecting a class it is only using this color: $('.myclass').css('background-color', '#dfe843');  
Give me a sec and i'll fix this for you.