# Querying an inline style property in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am writing a JQuery HTML parser for some particularly formatted HTML and I need to query an inline style for a value.

Within the code I am stepping through particular input fields and saving out this particular style to an array...

First here is the code I am using to step through these input fields and grab the widths. This works but does not return the correct width value (I want the EM value).

```
$('.inputBox',this).each(function(index)
{
   widthArray[widthArray.length] = $(this).attr('width');
}
```

Here is a simplified example of one of the input boxes

```
<input style="width:1.9500000000000002em;" maxlength="3" tabindex="1" class="inputBox" type="text">
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course the easiest way is to get it from the `style` attribute of `this`.

```
$('.inputBox', this).each(function(index) {
   widthArray[widthArray.length] = this.style.width;
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gQM7u/)

*From here on this is just drunken speculation*: theoretically, you can get the `style` attribute and split the values found in there based on `;`. Then you can further split them on `:` to get the key-value pairs.

Something like:

```
$('.inputBox', this).each(function(index) {
   var stylestemp = $(this).attr('style').split(';');
   var styles = {};
   var c = '';
   for (var x = 0, l = stylestemp.length; x < l; x++) {
     c = stylestemp[x].split(':');
     styles[$.trim(c[0])] = $.trim(c[1]);
   }
   widthArray[widthArray.length] = styles.width;
});
```

[Live Demo of Drunken Speculation](http://jsfiddle.net/G9USD/7/)

Answer (score 1):

unfortunatelly jquery actually serves only px-values - it's the same with the width() method, b.t.w.

A little dirty, but if "width" is the only style-element of your inputs, you could retrieve the whole style string and parse it by yourself:

```
var inputStyle = $("input").attr('style');
// make an array [ 'width', '1.9500000000000002em;' ]
var styleParts = inputStyle.split(':');
// make float from 1.9500000000000002em; --> 1.95
var widthEm = parseFloat(styleParts[1]);
```

Due to float precision in javascript you'll lose your ...0000002 at the end.
Maybe you'll need to parse the number with string methods.

Answer (score -4):

Because you checking the attrubute instead of the style width

```
$(this).css('width')
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that already, it returns a pixel width. I want the actual EM value declared in the style.

Comment: -1 this won't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475589/jquery-css-function-not-returning-expected-values/5476075#5476075