# Determine fluid or fixed width in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a reliable way to tell whether a web page's layout is fixed or fluid?  I don't care if it required a library like jQuery or MooTools so long as it's reasonably accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Typical `width` methods are going to give you pixels, but there's an answer here which should give you (in most cases) a percentage width if it is defined as such: [get CSS rule's percentage value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery/744450#744450)

Suspected caveats with this method:

- The width is declared in the first stylesheet (this could be modified as appropriate to search all stylesheets).
- The width isn't an inline style.
- You know the major container element of the page (this would be an issue with any method).