# jQuery .css returns back css property in pixels, when its actually in percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the value of the `left` property (which is in percent) using the `.css` method in jQuery:

```
var my_value= $("div").css("left");
```

Problem is, the above returns it in pixles...

Any idea on how I could get it to return the **actual** value of the property (which is in percentages)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get CSS rule's percentage value in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery)

Comment: Is `left` applied inline, or via a stylesheet?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I dont really know what you mean by inline or style sheet. But, the rule im trying to fetch is applied by javascript. When the page loads, an AJAX call is made, some calculations are done (for the percentages) and the css styles are applied to the document (simply inserted in the head section), for the elements to use.

Comment: @nav_nav: An inline style is applied via the `style` attribute on the element's tag, e.g. `<div style="left: 20%">`. When applied by a stylesheet, it's CSS in a `style` element or a CSS file linked via a `link rel="stylesheet"` element. From your comment, it sounds like it's applied by the stylesheet. If so, then I'm afraid your only option is to work through the style information (see my answer for details).

Comment: Ah yes, I did. So it looks like I should just stick with pixles?

Comment: @nav_nav: That would be easiest. As I said, it's *possible* to get the information from the style sheets, it's just difficult.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're applying `left` inline, you can access it directly from `style.left`, e.g.:

```
var my_value = $("div")[0].style.left;
```

For me, on Firefox, IE, and Opera, that returns the percentage value where `css` returns the number of pixels. (On Chrome, I get the percentage either way.)

If you're applying `left` via a stylesheet, I don't believe there's any *convenient* way to get the information you're looking for. You **can** get it, but it's really inconvenient: By looking through all of the defined style rules, figuring which ones apply to the element, and parsing the rule text. You can access the stylesheets via `document.styleSheets`, which is an array of all of the stylesheets for the document. Each style sheet will have an array of rules it defines available as either `cssRules` or `rules` (depending on the browser). Each rule has a `cssText` property that gives you the text of the rule.

```
$.each(document.styleSheets, function(sheetIndex, sheet) {
    $.each(sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules, function(ruleIndex, rule) {
        var ruleText = rule.cssText;

        // Figure out if the rule applies, and parse out the value
    });
});
```

Not easy getting all of the CSS rules of specificity and such right, but possible, and not especially difficult for simpler cases.

---

For the inline style stuff, [here's a live demo](http://jsbin.com/isozal) - In the demo, I have an absolutely-positioned `div` with `left` defined by an **inline** style and `top` defined by a stylesheet (so **not** inline).

Using Chrome 16:

```
css('left') says: 20%
style.left says: 20%
css('top') says: 10%
style.top says:
```

Using Firefox 10:

```
css('left') says: 193.2px
style.left says: 20%
css('top') says: 73.5px
style.top says:
```

Using IE9:

```
css('left') says: 239.8px
style.left says: 20%
css('top') says: 59.3px
style.top says:
```

The reason `style.top` is always blank is that `style` only reflects *inline* styles, but I included it for completeness.

Comment: Thats odd. `style.left` is returning nothing for me.

Comment: @nav_nav: On what browser? And is `left` applied inline, or via a style sheet? It matters (`style.left` will only be populated for an *inline* style).

Answer (score 6):

Just had this problem and managed to get it this way:

```
$('#mySelector').get(0).style.width;
```

returned me `'100%'`

however `$('#mySelector').css('width');`

returned me `'900px'`

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 4):

Update: in IE 11, style.left no longer works. If you are trying to access inline style, use the prop() function and then specify the specific attribute you're looking for as an array key:

```
$("selector").prop("style")["left"];
```

will return the property in pixels

Comment: Will return your what?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to get the width returned to you as a percentage, as the browser does the maths internally, and then only allows access to the resulting px value.

You can however work out the percentage once you know the width of the element, and the width of the relevant containing element, like this:

```
var elWidth = $('#myElement').width();
var containerWidth = $('#myContainer').offsetParent().width();
var elWidthPercent = 100 * elWidth / containerWidth;
```