# JavaScript and jQuery selectors produce different results?

Tags: jquery, javascript

The following 2 code snippets produce very different outcomes:

This one works as supposed: It increases the progressbar value (width) by 5 each second.

```
function doIncrement(increment) {
    w = parseInt(document.getElementById('internal-progressbar').style.width);
    document.getElementById('internal-progressbar').style.width = (w + increment) + '%';
    if (parseInt(document.getElementById('internal-progressbar').style.width) < 100)
    {
        setTimeout(function () { doIncrement(increment) }, 1000);
    }
}
```

This one (getelementbyid replaced with jquery selectors) produces an entire different outcome. It starts by increasing by 5 but then it increases by 34 and then by even more.

```
function doIncrement(increment) {
    w = parseInt($('#internal-progressbar').css('width'));
    $('#internal-progressbar').css('width', (w + increment) + '%');
    if (parseInt(document.getElementById('internal-progressbar').style.width) < 100)
    {
        setTimeout(function () { doIncrement(increment) }, 1000);
    }
}
```

What's causing this difference? I truly don't understand.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/k79Ph/

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log(w)` to see what's being returned?

Comment: Do these exist in the same scope? Does the difference continue if you declare `w` properly as `var w = parseInt...`?

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's `.width()` in the second place?

Comment: @still_learning you can still set the width with `.width()` you know. :) http://api.jquery.com/width/#width-functionindex--width

Comment: @TusharGupta
I tried making a fiddle (never done it before) but I couldn't even get the js function to be called properly.
Anyways here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/k79Ph/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `css('width')` returns the absolute size (in pixels), whereas `style.width` is the "raw" value (percentage). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227184/) should help you.