# How to get the value of a CSS property in SASS?

Tags: sass

I'd like to store the current value of a property for later use. It's already been solved for [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744319/96588).

The issue is that I'm using a `@mixin` to apply a CSS hack in several places ([Justified Block List](https://kristinlbradley.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/cross-browser-css-justified-block-list/)) and I'd like to restore the `font-size` property in `.block-list *` (currently *all* text in sub-elements is just collapsed).

Unsatisfactory workarounds:

- Save the global default font size in a separate file and pass it to the `@mixin` on `@import`. This is of course in the general case not the same font size as the objects which the mixin is applied to.
- Save the font size whenever you change it, and pass that. This tangles up the files involved, since it's not very elegant to `@include` the typography stylesheet in several otherwise unrelated files.
- Use more jQuery.

Possibly satisfactory workarounds:

- Override the font size with a stronger rule on the first ancestor which changes it. This could be tricky to determine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to tell the **computed** value of a property until the styles are actually applied to a document (that's what jQuery examines). In the stylesheet languages, there's no "current" value except the initial value or the value you specify.

*Save the font size whenever you change it, and pass that* seems best, and @BeauSmith has given [a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14095068/822138). This variant lets you pass a size or fallback to a defined global:

```
=block-list($font-size: $base-font-size)
  font-size: 0
  > li
    font-size: $font-size
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a mixin which is doing something "hacky" with the font size, then you will probably need to reset the font size as you have noticed. I suggest the following:

1. Create a Sass partial to record your projects config variables. I suggest `_config.sass`.
2. Define your base font-size in `_config.sass`:

   ```
   $base-font-size: 16px
   ```
3. Add `@import _config.sass` at the top of your main sass file(s).
4. Update the mixin to reset the font-size to your $base-font-size:

   ```
   @mixin foo
     nav
       font-size: 0 // this is the hacky part
       > li
         font-size: $base-font-size // reset font-size
   ```

***Note:** If you are using the SCSS syntax, you'll need to update the examples here.*