# Get CSS value as written in stylesheet with jQuery or RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex, css

I was looking at CSS3 [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/-moz-calc) and I wondered whether it is possible to subtract a value from the input string with jQuery (or RegEx).

For example:

```
div {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

I want to get the percentual value (`100%`) and the pixel value (`50px`) and I need to know what it is followed by (`px`, `em`, `pt`, `%`).

So basically:

- get a value after `calc(` and before a seperator (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`)
- get a value after the seperator and before `)`
- note that there could be more values than one!, e.g. `calc(100% - 20px - 0.8em)`

**EDIT:** 
Spudley talks of parsing the whole CSS stylesheet, but this might cause overhead. Because this a project *for the heck of it*, overhead is **allowed**, so you can go haywire and do whatever you want to accomplish this!

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @Alexander Just for fun, to see whether it is possible. And, if it is possible, one could write a jQuery plugin that alters `calc()` for older browsers.

Comment: I think what you need is CSS preprocessors : LESS or Sass. Because I am pretty sure calc is really inefficient.

Comment: @jerome.s I don't think I do. I am just wondering whether it is possible to get these values.

Comment: You will not be able to correctly parse arbitrary valid `calc()` expressions with a regex because they can contain nested matching parentheses (e.g. `(100% - 6px) / 2`), which you can't parse with a regular language.

Comment: @streetpc Let's say that those cases need not be included!

Comment: @Bram: Are you going to parse your own stylesheets? What input is given to your function?

Comment: Do you mean my own or an external sheet? Yes, my own sheet. I do not, however, understand your last question.

Comment: @Bram: Where are you hung parsing those values? Do you already have the string `"calc(100% - 50px)"`?

Comment: @Bergi No, that's part of the question. That line has to be extracted from the CSS file.

Comment: This question/answer could be relevant: [Get element CSS property value as it was set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/). But that only works in webkit.

Comment: @Qtax Thanks but I'd rather have a cross-browser solution OR an IE solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't really do or even need this in a real-life application but since you say this is just for fun; here is the fun part:

**Yes you can do it.** Loading the CSS file via AJAX calls is **not** the only way but it may be the only (but inefficient) way to make it really cross-browser. <s>Even the declaration below won't make it truly cross-browser since **`calc()`** function is [**not supported by all**](http://caniuse.com/calc) browsers and it's a CSS3 feature.</s>

***EDIT**: As of 2018, `calc` is supported by all modern browsers.*

```css
div {
    width: 300px; /* a fallback value for old browsers */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

You **can** get the raw CSS code from `document.styleSheets` and their rules. The **`cssText`** property of the rule will give you the full statement. But different browsers may parse the values with a `calc()` function differently.

I'll go with a more complex example to see how browsers treat the **`calc()`** function:

```css
calc(100% - -50px*6 + 4em/2);
```

This is how **Firefox** (v.18) treats it:

[image: calc() function in Firefox]

And this is how **Google Chrome** (v.24) treats it:

[image: calc() function in Chrome]

As shown; FF gets the non-prefixed `calc` value as it is and Chrome gets the `-webkit` prefixed value and re-parses it with nested parenthesis (if needed). If you don't declare it -webkit in Chrome; it will completely ignore the value. So, we should take these into account when we manipulate the calc statement.

Now, using the complex example; we will first get the statement inside the calc() function:

```
"100% - -50px*6 + 4em/2"
```

Then dissolve the elements of statement into an array:

```
["100%", "-", "-50px", "*", "6", "+", "4em", "/", "2"]
```

Finally, process the values and units of the array items to make them programmatically usable (as you wanted):

```
[{ value:100, unit:"%" }, "-", { value:-50, unit:"px" }, "*", { value:6, unit:undefined }, "+", { value:4, unit:"em" }, "/", { value:2, unit:undefined }]
```

The final result above includes the value-objects and operators (in order).

*Before reading further; note that the code below is not completely tested on all browsers and situations. It does not handle nested parenthesis parsing (like Chrome does) or, values with multiple or combined calc() functions. If you want to test this; I recommend Firefox since it does not parse nested parenthesis OR you can extend the code to enable support for them.*

```js
// Get the sheet you want to process. (assume we want to process the third sheet):
var sheet = document.styleSheets[2]; //you could also iterate all the sheets in a for loop
processRules(sheet);
```

```js
/** Iterates through the rules of the specified style sheet;  
 *  then dissolves and logs values including a calc() function.
 */
function processRules(sheet) {
    var rules = sheet.cssRules // Mozilla, Safari, Chrome, Opera
        || sheet.rules; // IE, Safari
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
        var rule = rules[i];
        // Check if we have a calc() function in this rule
        if (hasCalc(rule.cssText)) {
            // Get the calculation statement inside the calc() function.
            var statement = getCalcStatement(rule.cssText);
            // Dissolve the statement into its elements and log.
            console.log(dissolveCalcElements(statement));
        }
    }
}
```

```js
/** Checks whether the CSS value includes a calc() function, 
 *  (This is also for avoiding unnecessary regex.)
 */
function hasCalc(value) {
    return value.toLowerCase().indexOf('calc(') >= 0;
}

/** Gets the full statement (string) inside a calc() function.
 */
function getCalcStatement(rule) {
    if (!rule) return '';
    var pattern = /calc\(([^\)]+)\).*/;
    var match = pattern.exec(rule);
    return match && match.length > 1 ? match[1] : '';
}

/** Splits the calc operation's elements (values and operators) and 
 *  dissolves the values into objects with value and unit properties. 
 */
function dissolveCalcElements(statement) {
    // The CSS calc() function supports 4 basic math operations only: 
    // Addition (+), Subtraction (-), Multiplication (*), Division (/)
    // White-spaces are very important in a calc statement. 
    // From Mozilla: "The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace. 
    // The * and / operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is allowed, and recommended."
    // We could use: statement.split(/(\s+[\+\-]\s+|\s*[\*\/]\s*)/);
    // to include the operators inside the output array, but not all browsers 
    // support splicing the capturing parentheses into the array like that. So:
    statement = statement.replace('*', ' * ').replace('/', ' / ');
    var arr = statement.split(/\s+/);

    console.log("arr", arr);
    var calcElems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var d = dissolveElement(arr[i]);
        calcElems.push(d);
    }
    return calcElems;
}

/** Dissolves the value and unit of the element and 
 *  returns either the operator or an object with "value" and "unit" properties.
 */
function dissolveElement(val) {
    // Check if the value is an operator.
    var ops = '+-*/';
    if (ops.indexOf(val) >= 0) return val;

    var o = {};
    // CSS units in a calc statement can have all the regular units. 
    // According to W3C; they can also, can include a "vw" unit (stands for viewport).
    var pattern = /([\+\-]?[0-9\.]+)(%|px|pt|em|in|cm|mm|ex|pc|vw)?/;
    // Exec the value/unit pattern on the property value.
    var match = pattern.exec(val);
    // So we reset to the original value if there is no unit.
    if (match) { 
        var v = match.length >= 2 ? match[1] : match[0];
        o.value = toFloat(v); //parse value as float
        o.unit = match.length >= 3 ? match[2] : '';
    }
    else {
        o = { value:val, unit:''};
    }
    console.log("dissolve", match, val, o);
    return o;
}

// Helper Functions
function toFloat(value) { return parseFloat(value) || 0.0; }
```

That's it. As I mentioned, I wouldn't do this but it's always good to know if anything is possible.

***Note***: Since you mentioned making a jQuery plugin (for fun); you don't really need jQuery for this. And calling functions like `$('div').css('width')` will only give you the computed value, not the raw calc statement.

Answer (score 1):

The short simple answer here is no, you can't do that. The browser APIs won't give you the raw CSS code, so you can't do what you're asking.

About the only way you're going to achieve this is to load the stylesheet file into your javascript manually (ie via an Ajax call), and parse it. This is a *lot* of overhead for the browser.

It is a technique used by some polyfill scripts to implement CSS features that aren't available in certain browsers (eg [this script for Media Queries support in IE](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/), but for just checking values as you're doing I would say it's more effort than it's worth for a smaller question like this.

If you're willing to take the plunge and parse the whole CSS file manually in your JS code just for the sake of retrieving the calc values, then your best bet may be to crib the parsing code from one of the existing polyfill scripts. But if I were in your shoes I'd find an alternative solution to the underlying problem rather than trying to force this idea to its logical conclusion.

I guess the underlying problem is that question really needs to be turned on its head: Why do you have a CSS `calc` with fixed values of `100%` and `50px` if you don't know in the code what those values will be? The whole point of `calc` is to allow you to specify a combination of *known* values. This isn't some unknown user-entered value (or at least, it shouldn't be), so how come your Javascript doesn't know the values already?

If there is a disconnect between your JS and your CSS code, you should consider how to deal with it higher up the chain than the browser, because even if you do manage to get the values out of the `calc` using Javascript, it means that the browser will have to be doing that same set of processing over and over again on every page load, for values that are the same every time. That's a lot of wasted effort.

Comment: First of all: why doesn't my JS know what values are needed: because they differ from element to element (`each` function on certain elements). What would be nice to achieve is to write a plugin that detects `calc` in stylesheet and returns the output value of that calculation (in `px`) to that property. But, as said, this needs to work on a bunch of elements with different `calc` values, not just one, hence giving the JS values directly is not possible.

Comment: The use case for `calc()` is that is dynamic, and can handle relative and absolute values together. So *no*, you will not know the values.

Comment: WebKit has `getMatchedCSSRules()`. Example: [Get element CSS property value as it was set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that [no nested parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215256/get-css-value-as-written-in-stylesheet-with-jquery-or-regex/14445924#comment19721490_14215256) are used within `calc(...)` and assuming that the overhead of doing some regex matching against the whole css is acceptable, the following code

1. loads your css using [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/),
2. searches for *any* `: calc(...);` (a little dirty but probably sufficient),
3. extracts anything between the braces,
4. removes any operators and surrounding whitespaces,
5. alerts each operand including its unit.

You surely have to do a few adjustments according to your needs but I think this is basically what you wanted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("your.css", function(data) {
        var re1 = /: calc\((.*)\);/g;
        var re2 = /\s*[\-\+\/\*]\s*/;
        while (match = re1.exec(data)) {
            var arr = match[1].split(re2);
            for (i in arr) {
                alert(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you put the different values in different vars?

Comment: @BramVanroy You can iterate the array `arr` to get the values there. This is what `alert(arr[i])` does.