# How browser handles CSS color names in the source code

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to override how javascript converts complex CSS color names to rgb values when applying them to DOM elements.

For example: `document.getElementById("colorMe").style.background = "lightblue"`
will set the `div.style` object with a background = `rgb(...)`.

However,  `document.getElementById("colorMe").style.background = "blue"`will set the `div.style` object with a background = `blue`.

I would like to bypass how javascript is converting that color into an RGB value for **complex color names**.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you wanted to do this, I would use something server-side to plug in the right values.

Comment: Why not just _use the Chrome Inspector_ instead of "View Source?"

Comment: Doesn't "View Source" give you the source as authored?

Comment: @ExplosionPills -- that is true, edited to remove the "view source" part.  Basically I would like if I call `var x  = document.getElementById("colorMe").style.background` I would like that to show up as "lightblue" not "rgb(....)"

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215256/get-css-value-as-written-in-stylesheet-with-jquery-or-regex).

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply to all colors.  When I try `lightblue`, I do get rgb back on reading, but when I try `black` or `white`, I get those strings back rather than the rgb

Comment: @ExplosionPills exactly, which is why I'm thinking that this has to be possible because it works on simple color names.  The complex color names are being converted.

Answer (score 2):

The normalised format for CSS colours is `rgb(R,G,B)` for opaque colours, and `rgba(R,G,B,A)` for semi-transparent ones. No matter what you give as input, it is converted to one of these formats as output, and there's nothing you can do to chnge that.

However, you can save the name elsewhere, like this:

```
elem.setAttribute("data-color",elem.style.color = "lightblue");
```

Then just get `elem.getAttribute("data-color")` and you have your `lightblue` input.

Comment: In the chrome inspector I am allowed to specify a source of `style = "background: lightblue;"`, so this code is valid.  Is it javascript then, that is converting the value? And there is no way to overwrite that default conversion?

Comment: It's not JavaScript, it's just how the browser works internally. For instance, you *can* type `<b><i>blah</b></i>`, but the browser will convert it to `<b><i>blah</i></b><i></i>` - you won't see this except when you retrieve the DOM, just like you don't see the colour format change until you retrieve it.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe I asked the question improperly.  I don't believe this has to do with the browser, but how javascript converts colors in the `div.style` object.  I can do `div.style.background = "blue"` and it will store it as "blue", but doing `div.style.background = "lightblue"` will store it as `rgb(...)`, so that later, when I access that inside the javascript object, it does not return "lightblue".  I'm looking to override THAT functionality.  not the browsers.

Comment: That's browser-specific, I'm afraid.

Comment: I've asked the moderators to remove this question since all these answers began with the wrong question phrasing and title.  I've reposted with a proper title.  If it's browser-specific, perhaps there is a javascript cross-browser solution?  If you think you still have an answer to this I encourage you to post on the question I re-made: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641065/javascript-style-object-converts-complex-color-names-into-rgb)

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard called webcolors...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

When your browser reads lightblue it just translates it to 173 216 230.

Comment: I understand that, and when it reads red, javascript will not convert it to RGB, and instead will leave it as "red".  Is there a way to make lightblue NOT be converted within the `div.style` object when being set via javascript?

Comment: no, but if i understand what you are trying to do you can archive that with element.setAttribute('data-color', 'lightblue')... to keep track of that color thing...