# Javascript & CSS: how to get the value of the style sheet file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is an object with a class .selector
For him, it describes the style.

After the page loads done some javascript code which - it does not matter.
The result of the - CSS properties assigned to the object width of 110px.
How do I use javascript to get the width, which is written for the object in the file of styles?

In other words, how to get value (width = 150px), if the objects are assigned to the width equal 110px?

```
<style>
.selector {
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
</style>

<div class="selector"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selector').width('110');
    alert($('.selector').css('width'));
});
```

Here's an example of how to do so in the ALERT hatched 150 px instead of 100px?  http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/gn3f4590/1/

Comment: `style="110px;` is not a valid style attr.

Comment: This is a duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215256/get-css-value-as-written-in-stylesheet-with-jquery-or-regex

Comment: I don't think that duplicate ticket "How to get computed style of a HTMLElement" is the same as what the OP was asking. However it is a duplicate regardless.

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck Here's an example of how to do so in the ALERT hatched 150 px instead of 100px? http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/gn3f4590/1/

Comment: @djmartini, I see it alerting 110.. not 150. And in that example it gets the width value from the element. Not the stylesheet.

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck So I'm saying! And I need to get 150

Comment: @djmartini, Refer to this post. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215256/get-css-value-as-written-in-stylesheet-with-jquery-or-regex This is the same problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/man_luck/gn3f4590/

use;

```
$('.selector').css('width')
```

Comment: Here's an example of how to do so in the ALERT hatched 150 px instead of 100px?  http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/gn3f4590/1/