# how to detect percent width in css file with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want get width from css file with jquery but when use this method :

`$('element').width()` **OR** `$('element').css('width');` get pixel size element but in css file this element has percent size ....

how to get it.
**html :**

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

**css**

```
#content{width:50%}
```

Comment: You would need to read the CSS file itself. While `style="width:50%"` is retrievable via `element.style.width`, you can't do the same for stylesheet stuff.

Comment: how I read css file and retrieve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get element CSS property (width/height) value as it was set (in percent/em/px/etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/get-element-css-property-width-height-value-as-it-was-set-in-percent-em-px-et)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of being bored:

```
var mywidth = $('#content').width(),
    parentwidth = $('#content').parent().width(),
    percentagewidth = (mywidth*100)/parentwidth;
    alert(precentagewidth+"%");
```

==Rounding the number==

```
Math.round(precentagewidth)
```

[Math.round()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp) documentation.

Comment: my friend how to round this value??? (I do it but get this 19.8465467897465456%) I want to get 20% so how to round it?

Comment: @mohammad Edited the answer :) hope this is what you need

Comment: @mohammad if the answer solved your problem please do accept it