# js code for adding width of a class is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the width by adding 20%. My div class width in percentage. For example i have div with width 20%. I am using class name for stylesheet. When each time the page loading it want increase by 10%. The code is shown below. the avascript code `document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.width;` is not working` proper. Please help me.

**html**

```
<div class="box">
```

```js
var width = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.width;

var n = width + 20%;

width = n;
```

```css
.box{
  width:40%;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: `var n = width + 20%;` this is not valid javascript. You would have noticed if you ran your own code and checked the debugger.

Comment: [Get element CSS property (width/height) value as it was set (in percent/em/px/etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/get-element-css-property-width-height-value-as-it-was-set-in-percent-em-px-et)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line has a syntax error

> width + 20%;

If you want to calculate percentage then

```
width = width + width*20/100;
```

**Edit**

As @Rory pointed out in the comments, your width value isn't getting set because width value isn't getting fetched correctly at first place, here is the updated code

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
var width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(ele).width); //get computed style instead of style property
width = width + width*20/100;
document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.width = width;
```

**Edit 2**

As pointed out by @Anant, if you want to increase with in percentage, then

```
var fn = (elem) => ((elem.offsetWidth/(elem.offsetParent || elem).offsetWidth)*100).toFixed(2)+'%' ;
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
var width = parseInt(fn(ele)); //get computed style instead of style property
console.log(width);
//width = width + width*20/100;
width = (width + 20) + "%";
console.log(width);
document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.width = width;
```

**Demo**

```js
var fn = (elem) => ((elem.offsetWidth/(elem.offsetParent || elem).offsetWidth)*100).toFixed(2)+'%' ;

var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
var width = parseInt(fn(ele)); //get computed style instead of style property
console.log(width);
//width = width + width*20/100;
width = (width + 20) + "%";
console.log(width);
document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.width = width;
```

```css
.box{
  width:40%;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this is just increasing an integer value - it's not actually increasing the width of the `div` element. Also you can just do `width = width * 1.2`

Comment: I have used the code as "var width=document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.width;width = width + width*20/100;". But it is not working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have fixed that part as well. Thanks for pointing out the same.

Comment: @gurvinder372  it's about `%` not `px`.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh `%` works the same way as well, updated the demo.

Comment: @gurvinder372  still width is 40%

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Fixed that part as well. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: why 40+20 become 59% not 60%

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh It is becoming 60 on my machine on chrome 62.