# How to get complete css of element (classes, inline, @import,@media)

Tags: javascript, css

I want to work with CSS styles, so I get the needed info about this HTML

```html
<img src="imagelink" id="IMG" style="margin: 5px 4em 3% 2%;">
```

by this code

```js
if(window.getComputedStyle){
    style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
    for(var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++){
        var prop = style[i];
        var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
        returns[prop] = val; 
    }
    return returns;
}
```

Until now, I only work with "px", so all works fine.
Now I try to work with the other units and just I get trouble.

Instead of `5px, 4em, 3%, 2%`,  I receive from the computedStyle recalculate absolute values for "px".

```css
"margin-inline-start": "21.3667px"
"margin-left": "21.3667px"
"margin-right": "48px"​
"margin-top": "5px"
```

Why is it so and how I can prevent that? I want to work with the kind of unit which is defined in the inline CSS.

Recalculate this won't work, because I cannot see any info in the computedStyle that the original kind was not "px".

Thanks a lot for helping to understand and solving that.

UPDATE

I look around to find a way to get all matching rules for a element (css class, inline-style, @import and @media). But all what i find & read are half-workes or to old and wont work now)...i'm frustrated at this point

Comment: That's what `getComputedStyle` _means_, the computed value of the style! If you want the style as given instead, use, e.g., `element.style.marginLeft`

Comment: you mean HTMLElement.style? but not jquery.css() - hat should be computedStyle if i'm right?

Comment: HTMLELement.style seems to work only with inline css, how i can handle all styles, and get like in my example the correct unit "em" , "%" instead calculatet pixel?

Comment: I thought you only wanted the styles from the attribute only; sorry. Do any of the answers to [Find all CSS rules that apply to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2952667/1016716) help? Or any of the linked questions mentioned there?

Comment: i think that https://stackoverflow.com/a/37958301/10993949 could be a way, but i dont understand how i should use this code!?

Comment: This https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/eEvXXV produce a security error if you use css links outside your own domain - how i can solve this?

Comment: More straightforward, but still in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/get-element-css-property-width-height-value-as-it-was-set-in-percent-em-px-et/49144353#49144353

Comment: @Kaiido interesting, but helps me not for the moment. i go crazy, i could not find a way to gett all css styles for a elemen (class,inline,@import,@media). I look araound and around, mostly only half works or to old....