# With Javascript, how can I tell if a DOM element's font size is defined in px, em or rem?

Tags: javascript, css, font-size

I'm trying to parse a web page (any web page actually) and dynamically apply some adjustments to font sizes of DOM elements.

As far as I could see:

- `element.style.fontSize` will return the value plus unit, e.g.: `"11px"`, or `"1em"`, or `"1rem"`, which is fine for me, BUT...
- `element.style.fontSize` will return no value if the font size is defined via a css class. So if I want to address all DOM elements (most of which won't have their font-size defined in their `style` attribute), I'll have to use getComputedStyle instead, BUT...
- `getComputedStyle` seems to return all font sizes in px, even if it was originally defined in em or rem in the css, e.g.: font size defined as `"1rem"` => `getComputedStyle` returns `"16px"` instead.

For my purpose, I'd like to know the original font-size value with its original unit, so get `"1rem"` rather than `"16px"`.
Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/get-element-css-property-width-height-value-as-it-was-set-in-percent-em-px-et
Please have a look at this one.

Comment: [Only works in Chrome..](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to *dynamically* adjust font sizes, then `.style.fontSize` is the way to go. This is due to the fact that inline styles have a much higher level of specificity, so your changes will override any styles that may be present in the stylesheet.

[`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) returns the CSS value **after** "after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain". That means that the `rem` is taken into account and adjusted accordingly. Having said this, if you *need* to target based on existing values set in the stylesheet, I think `.getComputedStyle()` is the best bet. The fact that it shows the calculated value shouldn't make a difference; you're still able to manipulate 'changes' after the conversion -- and you can even convert back if need be.

Either way, you'll need to *set* the property with `.style.fontSize`.

Comment: I kinda like this answer... Since only [Chrome supports computedStyleMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap#Browser_compatibility) - outside of writing some hacky function yourself - why does it matter what the font-size was set in? If you can convert that value to `px` regardless how it was set - that should be good enough...

Comment: Actually, I first thought I could handle px as well. BUT: Suppose you're parsing nested elements. Starting with the first element, say you increase the font size by 20%. Fine. Then you get to a child element. Its font size is defined in em, but you don't know it. So you also increase its font size by 20% The trouble is: as soon as you had increased its parent's font size by 20%, the child's relative font size was also increased by 20%. So finally, you increased the child's font size by 44% instead of 20%. And it only gets worse then. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I finally changed my approach. Instead of parsing once, I parse twice. 1. I store all text elements and their original (computed) font sizes, in pixels. 2. Once the first loop is completed, I loop again and then adjust font sizes. It's the best way I've found to address both relative & absolute font sizes, without knowing which.