# How to get original styles just like we get with computedStyle property but without computation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I know we can get all the styles applied to an element using `window.getComputedStyle()` but the problem I am facing is that it converts different units to `px`. I want to fetch all the styles just like they appear in the style tab of the dev tool.

For example, It converts the line-height of `1.2` to `57.6px` but I need `1.2`. Is there a way to achieve that using pure JavaScript I am using React so I don't want to use jQuery.

I already went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/get-element-css-property-width-height-value-as-it-was-set-in-percent-em-px-et) question. The accepted answer suggests that one should use `computedStyleMap` but this method does not work on every browser another answer suggests using `getMatchedCSSRules` but now `getMatchedCSSRules` function is not available, it is removed.

Comment: *"I already went through this question. The accepted answer suggests that one should use `getMatchedCSSRules`..."* No, it doesn't. The **accepted** answer there doesn't mention that method at all.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's usually **really** badly received to tell people what to do when you're asking them for help. Instead of your opening meta paragraph, just list the questions you've found and say what about their answers doesn't work for you. A blanket "no trust me this isn't a duplicate" is not appropriate and, frankly, is likely to encourage downvotes and discourage help. *Show*, don't tell.

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The accepted answer uses `computedStyleMap ` which only works on a few browsers. The other which has more upvotes suggests using `getMatchedCSSRules`. Which is not available now. The thing is people don't even look at all the answers and mark the question as duplicate.

Comment: I want to fetch all the styles applied to a specific element without computation and I want it working on every browser especially Safari.

Comment: My point was that what you said in the question (about the linked question) is flatly wrong, which is unlikely to be useful in your cause to get an answer. "Every browser" is not achievable, be more specific.

Comment: what about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration  ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder answer that received the bounty is explicitely about window.getMatchedCSSRules() for chrome ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus style only returns inline styles, I already mentioned the problem with `getComputedStyle()`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated the question. :)

Comment: not only inline style, see the use

Comment: @G-Cyrillus - And **isn't** the accepted answer.

Comment: @AlqamaBinSadiq - I've posted an answer to the question you linked. :-)

Comment: Not sure why I didn't [link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61028626/157247) above... :-|

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please check my comment on your answer.