# How can I get a CSS value in its original unit with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Considering `getPropertyValue()` only return units in `px`, as far as I know, I wonder if there is a way, to get a CSS value, given by any way (inline CSS, external stylesheet…) in its original unit (em, vw, %).

```js
let el = document.querySelector('div')
let cs = window.getComputedStyle(el)
let height = cs.getPropertyValue('height')
el.innerText = height + " \n(I need to get 20vh)"
```

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  height:20vh;
  background:LawnGreen;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[edit] Not a duplicate of [Get element CSS property (width/height) value as it was set (in percent/em/px/etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/get-element-css-property-width-height-value-as-it-was-set-in-percent-em-px-et) as it seems to focus on `em` and `%` and as it is almost 10 years old, it ignores `vh`, and `vw`, and so are the answers.

Comment: `v(h/w)` is relative to viewport. Is extra calculation such as  `100 / (window.innerHeight / height)` not a viable solution for you?

Comment: Maybe you'll find a solution in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730612/get-element-css-property-width-height-value-as-it-was-set-in-percent-em-px-et

Comment: @HansSpieß I edited my question regarding this link

Comment: Did you try the answers and found they did not work with `vh` or `vw`? Because the accepted answer talks about using the `CSSUnitValue` API, which doesn't care about `em`, `%`, `vw` or any specific unit. The age of the question is irrelevant; the technologies used in your accepted answer are as old or older than the technologies used in the accepted answer in the duplicate.

Comment: Yes I did try the answer https://jsfiddle.net/168jbwp4/12/ (chrome / chromium only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun - this is wildly inefficient, but you could parse each stylesheet, check if each rule matches the element, if it does, add the rule to a list of matches.  Then, for each match, check if setting the inline style of that element to that rule changes the computed value, if it doesn't, assume that is the rule in use:

```js
const getCssActualValue = (el, property) => {
  const matches = new Set();
  const allCSS = [...document.styleSheets]
    .map(styleSheet => {
      try {
        return [...styleSheet.cssRules]
          .map(rule => rule.cssText)
          .join('');
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Access to stylesheet %s is denied. Ignoring...', styleSheet.href);
      }
    })
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map(rule => rule.split('}'))
    .forEach((styleSheet) => {
        styleSheet.forEach((rule) => {
            const [selector, styles] = rule.split(' {');
            try {
                if (selector && el.matches(selector)) {
                    styles.split(';').map(el => el.trim()).forEach((rule) => {
                        const [prop, val] = rule.split(': ')
                        if (prop === property) {
                            matches.add(val);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch {}
        });
    });
    return Array.from(matches);
  }
  

  const getCurrentCssValue = (el, property) => {
    const matches = getCssActualValue(el, property);
    const current = getComputedStyle(el)[property];
    const currentInline = el.style[property];
    for (const match of matches) {
        el.style[property] = match;
        if (getComputedStyle(el)[property] === current) {
            el.style[property] = currentInline;
            console.log({match});
            return match;
        }
    }
    el.style[property] = currentInline;
    return currentInline;
  }
  
  const property = 'height';
  const el = document.getElementById('test');
  el.innerText = getCurrentCssValue(el, property);
```

```css
#test{
  width:200px;
  height:20vh;
  background:LawnGreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: `if it doesn't,`  I assume you meant `if it does`..  Nice solution..!!

Comment: Great answer, thank you @dave