# How to get the width and unit (%, rem, em, vw etc) of an element in JS / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm writing a jQuery plugin and I want to wrap a `textarea` element (whose width could be defined in any unit) inside a `div` element and apply the original element's width and unit to the new parent. The pixel width is not useful, because I want the whole thing to be responsive.

```
<style>
  #target {
    width: 90%; /* 10rem, 80vw etc */
  }
</style>
<script>
  $(function(){
    let container=$('<div>');
    container.width(???); // make container's width whatever width and unit the textarea was in css - in this case 90%
    $('#target').wrap(container).css('width','100%');
  });
</script>

<textarea id="target"></textarea>
```

Expected result:

```
<div style="width: 90%"> <!-- or whatever width and unit was in the css -->
  <textarea id="target" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

Obviously it would be easy to get the exact pixel value with `outerWidth()` or `window.getComputedStyle`, but that wouldn't be responsive.

*Edit: Looks like this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49144353) already. It's possible, but only in Blink browsers for the time being.*

Comment: Why not just set `width: 100%` for the textarea?

Comment: Maybe `container.width($("#target").width())`

Comment: @philale `$("#target").width()` returns pixels

Comment: Could you make it responsive by responding to resize?

Comment: @AHaworth I could do it, but simulating the "responsiveness" on resize would be my last resort. I wanted to know first if there might be some other more clever ways.

Comment: You can find the jquery equivilent of the javascript ‘const rect = target.getBoundingClientRect()’ which gives you the latest/current dimensions of the text area, then use ‘rect.width’ to get the width. You could always wrap your function there inside a $(’#target’).on(‘input’… function so it updates as the user is typing in the textarea

Comment: I don’t now understand what is required. If you write 90% into the width of the parent div then the width of the text area will become 90% of that 90%. Why would that ever be reupquired?

Comment: @AHaworth I need to get the width and the unit of that width (be it px, percentage, rem, em, vh, vw etc) of an element so I can apply to another element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#target').wrap('<div id="container">'); // wrap the target in a div
    var containerWidth = $("#target").width() / $('#target').parent().width() * 100; //get width as a percentage
    containerWidth = Math.ceil(containerWidth); //round up to nearest whole number
    $("#container").css('width', containerWidth + '%'); //set the width of the container
});
```

If it has to be responsive send me a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but what I basically need is to get the width and the unit of an element so I can apply it to another element. The unit might be px, percentage, rem, em, vw, vh or whatever.

Comment: Is it possible for you to apply a css class to two elements? e.g. .bg-color { background-color: red;}

Then do

<div class="bg-color">
<div class="bg-color">

If Not can you get the width through the style or do you have to get it through the javascript element?