# How to determine in Java script the height of a div is in Percentage or pixels

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way in javascript to determine wether the height of the Div is in %

```
<div id="dvPercentage" style="height: 80%">
```

How do I get that the height of the div was given in Percentage.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery

Comment: Basically you mean to say there's no way ?

Comment: Seems like it. Anyhow, it is a feasible solution.

Comment: @timeNomad This doesn't apply because Pratim is asking about a property set in the style attr of the element not in a style sheet. See my answer below.

Comment: @timeNomad Well, it is a bit different for inline/own styles vs. the stylesheet/inherited styles asked about in that question. But, yes, those are generally limited to [*computed*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) or [*used*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/used_value) values.

Comment: Ill do but wait ill test first :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the the height of the style object of the element.

```
document.getElementById("objectId").style.height
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give back `true`

```
document.getElementById('dvPercentage').style.height.endsWith('%')
```

if `height` is in percent.