# How can I get padding-bottom style value as a % with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with a `%` based `padding-bottom`, ie.  `padding-bottom: 10%;`

When I run a simple

```
boxSize =  $('#secondBlob').css("padding-bottom");
alert(boxSize);
```

The result is actually a pixel value, not 10%;   Was hoping to get a result of "10%" or "10".  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the style inline or from a stylesheet?

Comment: Instead of boxsize I would alert the following: alert((100 * boxsize / screen.availHeight) + "%");

Comment: @SmokeyPHP from a stylesheet

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery) might help you. :)

Comment: @Mark If you don't want to compute it, you may need to go through the `document.styleSheets` object to get the actual value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems theres no clean way to do this :(  But here is a hacky way to do it, and it does work:

```
$('.parent').hide();
var boxSize = $('#secondBlob').css("padding-bottom");
$('.parent').show();

alert(boxSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

**this function**

```
<div id="Div">Last Div</div>
<p class="salida">salida</p>
```

jquery

```
$('#Div').css({
    'padding-bottom':'10%',
    'background':'pink',
    'color':'#333'
});
$('.salida').text($('#Div').css('padding-bottom'));
```

## =======================================

```
<div id="lastDiv" style="padding-bottom: 10%;">Last Div</div>
<br /><br />
<div id="output"></div>

#lastDiv {
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    width: 33%;
}

$("#output").text("CSS: "+$("#lastDiv").css("padding-bottom"));
//wrong
$("#output").append("<p>Style: " + $("#lastDiv")[0].style.width + "</p>");
```

or

```
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div style="right:80%;">c</div>
<p>
wrong
</p>

div:last-child{
    right:80%;
}$(function() {
var c =$('div').last().get(0);//.css('right');
$('p').text(c.style.right);
});
```