# Value Stored in Var as Percent but outputs it as pixels

Tags: jquery, html, css, output, var

I want to animate a div by mouse-over to change it's width.
When mouse-leave, I want the div's width to be as it was before the animation.

Since I want this snippet to work with different div's (with different widths), I cant just write the width values but have to store the initial width inside a var.

The input for my var is 20%. It gets this value from my CSS file.

```
 Var oldwidth = $tab.css('width')
```

After it animated the width to 10, it then animates the width back to var=oldwidth. Oldwidth should be back to 20% but it is now an integer value.

```js
$("#zeile-1").mouseenter(function(event) {
  $("#zeile-1 .tab.empty").each(function() {
    var $tab = $(this)
    if (this.hasAttribute("animating")) return
    var oldWidth = $tab.css('width') //here the Var stores my Value (20%) from my css.//
    $tab.attr("oldWidth", oldWidth)
    $tab.attr("animating", "mouseenter")
    $tab.animate({
      width: "10"
    }, 1000);
  })
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $("#zeile-1 .tab.empty").each(function() {
    var $tab = $(this)
    if ($tab.attr("animating") == "mouseleave") return
    var oldWidth = $tab.attr("oldWidth")
    $tab.attr("animating", "mouseleave")
    $tab.animate({
      width: oldWidth //here it outputs the value but as px//
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      complete: function() {
        $tab.removeAttr("animating");
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```
<body>
      <div class="zeile" id="zeile-1">
        <div class="a tab">31.</div>
        <div class="b tab empty">&emsp;</div>
        <div class="c tab">MAR</div>
        <div class="d tab empty">&emsp;</div>
        <div class="e tab empty">&emsp;</div>
        <div class="f tab">201</div>
        <div class="g tab empty">&emsp;</div>
        <div class="h tab empty">&emsp;</div>
        <div class="i tab">8</div>
      </div>

.tab {
  height: auto;    
}

.a{
    width: 11%;
}
.b{
    width: 10%;
}
.c{
    width: 17%;
}
.d{
    width: 17%;
}
.e{
    width: 17%;

and so on..
```

Can I tell the Var to store my value in % and to output it as %?

Comment: Custom attribute should start with `data-*` like `data-oldWidth`. Why not just use css `#zeile-1 .tab.empty:hover` ?

Answer (score 0):

> After it animated the width to 10

What you meen by 10? you need to choose the unit you want to use, if pixel then use `px` if precent then use `%`, You need to specify the unit in your animate function like :

```
$tab.animate({
    width: '10px'
    //Or
    width: '10%'
}
```

In the `oldWidth` also you need the unit :

```
$tab.animate({
    width: oldWidth+'px'
    //Or
    width: oldWidth+'%'
}
```

**NOTE :** `Var` should be `var` with `v` in lowercase.

Comment: if I say 
$tab.animate({
width:  '10%'
} 
and
$tab.animate({
    width: oldWidth+'%'
}

it animates to 10% and then stops working

Comment: Ok please add the HTML code to your question so we could check with you...

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `css()` function will always return a calculated width value instead of the original value (in this case, a percent). There are two ways you can go about getting the original percent value:

You can get an inline width value with this code: `$(selector)[0].style.width`. The problem with this solution is that if your style is originally in a stylesheet instead of inline, it will not retrieve the value.

The way you may get around that is to clear the inline value that you previously set with: `$(selector).css('width', '')`. Obviously, this would clear a previous inline value you may have set but the element would still use any value defined in a stylesheet. You might want to check if there was a previous width value set with the first bit of code and maintain that state for when you need to revert.

Note that there are other solutions (such as a hide/show) here: [get CSS rule's percentage value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery). The hide/show one will not flicker an element because the element wouldn't update in-between the two steps I think.