# How to access CSS properties on DOM object?

Tags: javascript, css

My element has a CSS rule applied to it giving it `left: 0%`. When I access that element with JS and use `el.style.left`, I get an empty string. When I use `window.getComputedStyle(el)`, it gives me a pixel value. How can I access the actual `"0%"` that the CSS has set it to? I need to be able to read this.

I'm only using `left` as an example though....same goes for all the other CSS properties on the element. How can I see them?

Comment: I'm afraid that this information gets lost. `el.style` only works if the rule is inside the `style` attribute. The computed value is memorized in a format that is useful for the browser, so it only returns pixels. Maybe you could read the css file. Btw I wait for other solutions

Comment: A workaround could be getting the pixel value and compare it with the parent element's width, so you get the percentage.

Comment: Clever idea! Might try that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery

Comment: That would make this a duplicate, I do believe.