# Get inline css width property from element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this element:

```
<div class="progress xs" style="margin-bottom: 0px; height: 3px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 100%;"></div>   
</div>
```

I want to get the inline `css` property width.

I tried to do this:

```
$(".progress").find(".progress-bar").css('width');
```

Which should return '`100%`' but returns `638px` instead.
As you can see in my example :

```js
console.log($(".progress").find(".progress-bar").css('width'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress xs" style="margin-bottom: 0px; height: 3px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 100%;"></div>   
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to get the `100%` of the `progress-bar` element?

Comment: what do you mean by container?

Comment: See the second answer in the duplicate I marked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432934/519413

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly access the `style` property of the element to get the defined width.

```js
console.log($(".progress").find(".progress-bar").css('width'));
console.log($(".progress").find(".progress-bar")[0].style.width);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress xs" style="margin-bottom: 0px; height: 3px;">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah great thanks that `[0]` did it, I already tried to do something like that but never knew `[0]` has to be before that

Comment: @Enthu its already answered and accepted.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph , hi , I have commented , it is not working fine for more than one box , I have commented in the last, please help