# Get last applied CSS rule for width using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I need to get the last applied CSS rule for the `width` attribute on an HTML element using Javascript.

Example 1:

```html
<input type="text" class="fullwidth"/>
```

```css
input {
  width: 300px;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Example 2:

```html
<input type="text" class="fullwidth halfwidth"/>
```

```css
input {
  width: 300px;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.halfwidth {
  width: 50%;
}
```

I need to get `100%` for the first case and `50%` for the second one. Basically I need the following highlighted value:

[image]

I can't use the `getComputedStyle` method because it retrieves the computed width in pixels, but I need the same value in the CSS rule.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/744450/7867822

Comment: Actually if you only want percentages and px as they've been set, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/19873734/3702797 might be better but doesn't work on units like em, vw etc.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you, that answer helped me a lot.