# Is there a way to get the original CSS unit of an element instead of getting px values through getComputedStyle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, chromium

Okay so let's imagine I have an element that has a CSS like this:

```
.element {
  width: 90vh;
}
```

Now if we do `getComputedStyle` it gives you values in `px` but I want to know the original unit being used. Be it `em`, `rem`, `vh` or anything else.

Now I did stumbled upon a hacky way from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery/36460652#36460652) on SO, but when working with say suppose `vh` then it gives value in `px` again but works fine in detecting `auto`, `%` (I am happy that we got  atleast these  But I need all!)

**Why am I doing this?**

Because I am making a tool and I need* this functionality for better user experience.

---

Now the other solution is to loop over all the stylesheets and calculate specificity and then return the value (which is my last option).

So all I wanted to ask is that is there not any native api, hack or function that just tells me the original CSS unit used on an element?

I mean when going on chrome devTools we can see the original unit being shown:
[image]

Can't we access that value from browser api or something? I am open to make it an electron/tauri app too if they could provide me something like that. I don't know, I am just so lost...